# Perform an item operation from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have created two dictionaries that are related to each other, the case is that I must perform addition and division operations, but I have stalled in one part:

```
dict1 = {1: [20900], 2: [20900], 3: [20900]}

dict2 = {1: [2.5], 2: [5.0], 3: [7.5]}

dict3 = {key:[dict1[key][0]*(dict2[key][0])] for key, valor in dict2.items()}
```

What I am looking for is to accumulate the sum of the **dict3** items, and then divide it for each of their respective items, something like this:

```
Cumulative sum of dict3 items = 52250 + 104500 + 156750 = 313500
```

Then divide this quantity for each of the 3 items, finally the dictionary I'm looking for would look like this:

```
dict3 = {1: [0.1667], 2: [0.333], 3: [0.500]}
```

My problem is when dividing that accumulated number. It should be clarified that **dict1 and dict2** will always have 1 single list item in each key.

I would greatly appreciate help with this problem, regards.

Comment: If you always have one item in those lists, why use lists?

Comment: Because those items come from other operations previously performed, but thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After constructing `dict3` as you have already done

```
dict3 = {key:[dict1[key][0]*(dict2[key][0])] for key, valor in dict2.items()}
```

You can calculate the cumulative sum using [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and a dictionary comprehension

```
dict3_sum = sum(value[0] for value in dict3.values())
```

And then divide each element of dict3 by the calculated sum

```
dict3 = {key: [value[0]/dict3_sum] for key, value in dict3.items()}
```

Comment: @Dan Because `dict3.values() ` are lists containing a single value, `sum(dict3.values())` doesn't work. (`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
`)